# simple example of thread crossing application domains?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, appdomain

I've been reading up a bit on Application Domains and Threading, and I came across this statement:

*"A particular thread is not confined to a single application domain. That is, threads are free to cross application domain boundaries; a new thread is not created for each application domain."*

Now that's all well and good, but I thought to myself - when exactly is that crossing of domains by the thread going to happen?

I have seen examples of people creating Application Domains and using CreateInstanceAndUnwrap and MarshalByRefObject. But - marshalling is available between completely seperate processes! So meh - that's not what I call "free to cross".

Can anyone provide example (C#) code of a thread crossing application domains without marshalling, as I do not consider this "free"? (or am I just totally muddled up as usual).

Answer (score 2):

Well, simple, CreateInstanceAndUnwrap() makes the thread cross the AppDomain barrier.  After all, the created object exists in the AD, the thread must make the transition in order to call the constructor.  Additional crossing happen when you then make calls through the proxy to call the class methods.

And AppDomain is *not* a barrier for code, it isolates data.  Each AD has its own GC and loader heap.  Serialization is required to cross that data barrier.  But it is the exact same thread to deserializes again and continues execution.  Which is quite distinct from marshaling between processes, that *has* to happen between two distinct threads.  With the considerable overhead of marshaling between distinct virtual memory views and the required thread context switch.  An AD is a *much* cheaper version of a process.

Comment: But isn't this a security loophole?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe a user thread can cut across multiple appDomains. However, CLR worker threads, GC threads and the like will and can do.

Answer (score 0):

One example could be calling native code and the native code calls a callback in another appdomain.

And marshaling inside a process might use an optimized route where the same OS thread is used in multiple AppDomains.